# how to get build number for jenkins job via python code

Tags: python, jenkins

I am developing a python code to deal with jenkins using the *jenkinsapi* package. I am looking for a simple way to pass the job name and get the latest build number for that job. Example

```
from jenkinsapi import jenkins
ci_jenkins_url = "job url"
username = None
token = None
job = "Test 3"
j = jenkins.Jenkins(ci_jenkins_url, username=username, password=token)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    j.build_job(job)
```

This is triggering builds successfully, but I need to get the build number for proceeding further. Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 5):

There are 2 ways :

**Way 1:**
Using following APIs -

- Access the same data as Python for Python clients :

  http://(jenkins_url):8080/job/(jobname)/api/python?pretty=true
- Access the same data as JSON for JavaScript-based access :

  http://(jenkins_url):8080/job/(jobname)/api/json?pretty=true
- Access data exposed in HTML as XML for machine consumption :

  http://(jenkins_url):8080/job/(jobname)/api/xml

From above URls, you can get latest build number from `builds` block.
For more details : check `http://(jenkins_url):8080/job/(jobname)/api/`

**Way2 :** Using `jenkinsapi` module

```
import jenkinsapi
from jenkinsapi.jenkins import Jenkins
server = Jenkins(jenkins_url,username=<<>>,password=<<>>)
print(server.get_job("jobname").get_last_buildnumber())
```

Answer (score 2):

The *Job* object implements several methods for getting the build number of the last build, last completed build, last stable build, etc.

```
jenkins_server = jenkins.Jenkins(ci_jenkins_url, username=username, password=token)
my_job = jenkins_server.get_job('My Job Name')
last_build = my_job.get_last_buildnumber()
```

You can use Python interactively to explore the API for packages that don't have complete online documentation:

```
>>> jenkins_server = jenkins.Jenkins(...)
>>> job = jenkins_server.get_job('My Job Name')
>>> help(job)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, its working. I did also try this..... last_build_number = j.get_job_info('test_api')['lastCompletedBuild'] ['number'], this threw Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/trishal/PycharmProjects/python-jenkins/get_build_number.py", line 8, in <module>
   last_build_number = j.get_job_info('Test 3')['lastCompletedBuild'] ['number']
AttributeError: 'Jenkins' object has no attribute 'get_job_info'

Process finished with exit code 1, not sure if I am using get_job_info correctly

Comment: @Trishal the Jenkins object does not have a _get_job_info_ method.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is solved. Had uninstalled slack-api and installed python-jenkins only. Now the documented methods are working

Answer (score 0):

When you submit a job using `build_job()` api it sends it to the queue where the job roughly waits around 5secs before being executed.
During this time if you execute `get_queue_item(queue_id)` you will see `why: In the quiet period. Expires in 3.7 sec` in the response. To get the build id of the job you just submitted you need to wait till the job gets out of the queue and that when the response for `get_queue_item(queue_id)` is updated with job details.

Sample code:

```
new_job = server.build_job('test-job') # returns queue id of the new build

while True:
    queue_info = server.get_queue_item(new_job)
    if queue_info['why'] is None:
        print(f"The job url is {queue_info['executable']['url']}")
        break
```

Sample response:

```
{
    '_class': 'hudson.model.Queue$LeftItem',
    'actions': [
        {
            '_class': 'hudson.model.CauseAction',
            'causes': [
                {
                    '_class': 'hudson.model.Cause$UserIdCause',
                    'shortDescription': 'Started by user ****',
                    'userId': '*****',
                    'userName': '****'
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    'blocked': False,
    'buildable': False,
    'id': 30,
    'inQueueSince': 1708121493104,
    'params': '',
    'stuck': False,
    'task': {
        '_class': 'hudson.model.FreeStyleProject',
        'name': 'test-job',
        'url': 'http: //opense-jenki-*********/job/test-job/',
        'color': 'blue_anime'
    },
    'url': 'queue/item/30/',
    'why': None,
    'cancelled': False,
    'executable': {
        '_class': 'hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild',
        'number': 28,
        'url': 'http://opense-jenki-**************/job/test-job/28/'
    }
}
```